# Proper name as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

It is common to use proper names as adjectives. However, the right use is not always clear to me. To illustrate the question, I'm considering the examples below:

1. In Newton's theory, objects have mass.
2. In the Newton theory, objects have mass.
3. In Newton theory, objects have mass.

According to me, 1. and 2. are correct, above. I am not sure about 3. Are there systematic rules on this matter? Also, there might be additional difficulties when a sentence is started with the proper name:

4. Newton theory was developed...
5. The Newton theory was developed...

I am undecided. We could also have an additional adjective as follows:

6. The preferred Newton assumptions are...
7. Preferred Newton's assumptions are...

Not to be confused with Newton's preferred assumptions.

[**EDIT**] What happens when two proper names are combined, with for instance, something like:

8. In the Lebesgue-Kolmogorov theory
9. In Lebesgue-Kolmogorov's theory

Comment: Example (1) is standard; (2) and (5) are uncommon and sound a bit strange but are acceptable; (3) and (4) would never be used.

Comment: This question has also been posted on [writing.se] at [Proper names as adjective](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/39959/2533)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Chappo's comment, and would add that regarding 6 & 7, the work Newtonian would be useful.

Definition of Newtonian

> 1 : of or relating to Sir Isaac Newton or his doctrines

[m-w source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Newtonian)

Comment: Great idea for "Newtonian"! I had not thought about it.